# How do I incorporate secrets manager in my python script?

Tags: python, aws-secrets-manager

Here is part of the code I am using in my script ClassName.py:

```
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import json
from SecretsManager import SecretsManagerSecret as sms

class ClassName:
    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)

    def DB_connection(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        try:
            config=ClassName.get_config(self)
            secret = ClassName.get_secret(config["config-name"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_name"])
            username=secret[config["config-name"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_username"]]
            password=secret[config["config-name"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_password"]]
            host=config["config-name"]["database-secrets"]["host"]
            port=config["config-name"]["database-secrets"]["port"]
            database=config["config-name"]["database-secrets"]["db"]

            connection = pm.connect(user=username,password=password,host=host,port=port,database=database)

            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection

    def get_secret(name=None):
        if name is None:
            print('Secret name required.')
        secret_name = name?????
```

Here is my SecretsManager.py script:

```
import boto3
import json

def SecretsManagerSecret():

    client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

    aws_sec_name = "secret_name"
    aws_sec_key = "secret_username"
    resp = client.get_secret_value(SecId=aws_sec_name)
    
    aws_sec_val = json.loads(resp['SecretString'])
    result = {
        "SecKey": aws_sec_val[aws_sec_key],
        "SecPW": aws_sec_val["SecPW"]
    }
    return result
```

My issue is, I don't know how to incorporate `SecretsManager.py` that my co worker wrote into the `ClassName.py` script I wrote. I think I need to add a function in `ClassName.py`, which I started to add called `def get_secret()` to actually grab the secret information in `SecretsManager.py`. I don't know how to write that function to extract the secret in the other file. I think I incorporated the function `def get_secret()` correctly in the try block but I am not sure how to actually make `ClassName.py` read the secret.